# Weak convergence and norm-convergence in Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$\text { Let }\left\{x_{n}\right\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text { be a sequence in a Banach space } X$, $\text { if } p=\infty \text { and }\left(c_{n}\right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in \ell^{\infty}$, is there a example show that$ \sum c_{n} x_{n} $ need not  converge in the norm of $ X?$

Also, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \mu\left(x_{n}\right) \text { converges for each } \mu \in X^{*}$?
My attempt is to show partial sum is cauchy, but I'm confused which norm we should use, since $\mu(x_n)$ is just a scalar, should we use $\ell^{\infty}$ norm?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ to be a sequence *such that* $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n x_k\in X$: consider for instance $X=\Bbb R$, $x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}$, $c_n=(-1)^n$. Hence of course the particular counterexample $\mu(x)=x$ for the second question.

Comment: Why is the presume is needed? How about there is nothing special about $\{x_n\}$?

Comment: @Maskoff Then it's even easier, but the counterexample applies.

Comment: Did you use absolute value for determining the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} c_{n} \mu\left(x_{n}\right)$?

Comment: @Maskoff What are you talking about? $\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n\mu(x_n)$ is a series in $\Bbb R$, like you said in the question.

Comment: My bad, I was think that $c_{n} \mu\left(x_{n}\right)$ is in $\ell^{\infty}$